# show that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

show that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Here is the algebric proof:

We have $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$, and we want to show  that $\lim a_n=0$.

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

So, when $n\to\infty$, we get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\to 0$.

Question: I am wondering does episilon-delta method work here as an alternative proof?

Comment: As far as I know, the epsilon-delta method could at least *in theory* be applied to any limit type question to prove or disprove a particular result, although it will often be longer & more difficult than other methods. Is there anything in particular about using the epsilon-delta method you were wondering about?

Comment: @JohnOmielan no just in general. but how can it be more difficult?

Comment: By "difficult", I meant sometimes not particularly obvious how to apply it. Perhaps the use of "difficult" was not the best choice.

Comment: It would be epsilon-$N$ method since the limit is at infinity -- given positive epsilon, show that there exists $N$ such that $n > N$ implies the given expression is less than epsilon (the absolute value is redundant since the expression is positive for all positive $n$).

Comment: Do you understand the lemmas that your "algebraic proof" relies on? If you unwind the proofs of those lemmas in your particular example, then you will get an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof. However, there is no need to do that and the outcome will be tedious and less informative than the structured proof that uses the lemmas. The answers to your quetion that have just been added indicate how tedious the $\epsilon$-$N$ proof is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $N > 0$ such that 
$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}<\varepsilon$ when $n>N$. Your algebraic manipulation shows that
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$
so you would like to solve the inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} < \varepsilon$.

To find $N$ it is enough to note that $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} > 2\sqrt{n} > \varepsilon^{-1}$, and the last gives $n > 1/4\varepsilon^2$. Set $N$ to be the least integer greater than $1/4\varepsilon^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The epsilon-delta method requires you to work out how small a $\delta$ is sufficient for a sought $\epsilon$, so you need your calculation anyway. You want to prove$$\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\left(\forall n>\frac{1}{\delta}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon\right)\right).$$It suffices to take $\delta=4\epsilon^2$. Or if we use the more typical $\epsilon$-$N$ definition, take $N=\frac{1}{\delta}=\frac{1}{4\epsilon^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{n}$, so, $\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} > 2\sqrt{n}$ and then
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \ .$$
Now, let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $4\varepsilon^2$ is a *positive* real number, by the Archimedian property of $\mathbb{R}$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$0< \frac{1}{N} < 4\varepsilon^2.$$
It follows that for $n \geq N$, $2\sqrt{n} \geq 2\sqrt{N}$ and then
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} < \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \leq \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{N}} < \varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have shown that $a_n$ can make arbitrarily small for sufficiently large $n$. Hence, $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, the "algebraic proof" in spruce's argument has to be finished off by observing that the functions $n \mapsto \sqrt{n+1}$ and $n \mapsto \sqrt{n}$ both tend to $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, hence the same holds for $n \mapsto \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}$ which implies that $n \mapsto {1 \over \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. So this proof leaves the $\epsilon$s and $N$s where they belong in low-level lemmas about simple functions and uses intuitive facts about monotonicity to derive the desired result from those lemmas. Unwinding this to get $\epsilon$-$N$ estimates is pointless unless you actually need those estimates.